# Why is the blog not themed?

Tags: feature-request, design, blog

The [English Language & Usage Community Blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com/) has the lovely EL&U theme. The [Christianity Community Blog](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/) still has the beta theme. Why?

Supplementary question: What happened to the title “Eschewmenical”?

Comment: A better question is "How can we motivate users to participate on the blog?" Because a lack of motivation is why it is inactive.

Comment: @fredsbend Two words: Writer's Block.

Answer (score 4):

In short, because we haven't asked, SE only currently employs 1 designer (who is insanely busy), and it's probably not worth pushing for unless we relaunch the blog.

As far as the title goes, I'm guessing if we ever push for a new design, we'll have the opportunity to add our title. If memory serves we talked about changing to title with SE and they said wait til you graduate.

Comment: Good news!  We've hired a few more designers.  Bad news: We hired a few more designers because we have more need.  Unfortunately, the fallow Christianity.SE blog hasn't even made that list yet.  When it does make a triumphant comeback, feel free to ping a Community Manager and we'll add it to the design queue.